# sentence formation using such and so

Tags: grammar

I have two questions:

1. I have the following sentence:

   > "It was so extensive an area that"

   why do we prefer to write the above sentence instead of

   > "The area was so extensive that"
2. Can we use "such" instead of "so" like:

   > "It was such an extensive area that"

Comment: It-clefts often give an emphasis (to the subject, descriptors) by postposing. There's no other reason for choosing this over the rather banal "The area was so extensive that ..." say. Here, 'such an' and 'so ... an' are equivalent; the version with 'so' might again be preferred as adding slightly more emphasis ('such' sounding softer, less acute).

Comment: We do not prefer to write "It was so extensive an area that" instead of "The area was so extensive that". The latter is actually *much* more common.

Answer (score 1):

It would be correct to say "It was so extensive that," but not "it was so extensive an area."

It's more common to say "it was such an extensive area that," or "the area was so extensive that."

I think in the first sentence (above) "so" is an adverb helping extensive," in the second "so" is used as an adjective helping "area".

"Such" can be an adjective, but "so" can't I believe, (not 100% sure).

Comment: Actually, _so extensive an area_ is perfectly OK. And you're right about different grammatical functions, though the difference between adjective and adverb is not what's involved. Naming things does not explain them.